# LyX unable to access needed font resources

Tags: fonts, lyx, mactex, mathdesign

I'm getting an error in LyX when I attempt to use certain features that require access to font resources, even though these same features work fine in TexShop.

For example, if I attempt to enable "expert" options for `mathdesign`, so that I can access small caps, the minimal code that does this works as expected in TexShop, but when I use the same code in LyX, I get an error

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file bchrc8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
```

unless I remove the "expert" option (in which case I can't get small caps in the running headers in the example).

```
\documentclass[nohyper,sfsidenotes]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[bitstream-charter,expert]{mathdesign}

\title{This is the title and running head}

%As an example, use sans small caps in the running header 
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\sffamily\smallcaps{\newlinetospace{\plaintitle}}\quad\thepage}

\begin{document}
Body text.
\newpage{}
More body text.
\end{document}
```

All the files are where they should be, and are up to date, in my MacTeX 2011 installation (and clearly TeXShop is finding them).

---

TeXLive logs the following just before succeeding:

```
{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/ly1/texnansi.enc}
{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}
</usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/bchr8a.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/helvetic/uhvr8a.pfb>
```

LyX logs the following just before failing:

```
{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}
{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/ly1/texnansi.enc}
</usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/bchb8a.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/bchr8a.pfb>
```

Comment: AFAIK, the `expert` option tries to access the "Expert" fonts that are usually sold by font vendors and not available in free form.

Comment: @egreg: The MWE works in TexShop though, and the relevant files are all present.

Comment: Are you sure that LyX is using the same TeX distribution as TeXShop?

Comment: @egreg: I'm almost certain, yes. And the line that precedes the above error in the log is the full path to the location of the relevant font resource (`/usr/local/texlive/2011/t
exmf-dist/fonts/type1/bitstrea/charter/bchr8a.pfb`, so LyX knows where it is).

Comment: Then I suspect a permission issue. What's the output of `ls -l $(kpsewhich bchr8a.pfb)`? You have to use the Terminal for this.

Comment: @egreg: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  34869 Jan  9  2006 ./bchr8a.pfb`

Comment: @egreg: Note also my addition to the question above, showing differences in the logs.

Comment: Of course the error shows when you remove `\sffamily` from the `\fancyhead` instruction. Which is just because of the expert option and what I told you in my first comment: you were using two different examples.

Comment: @egreg: I'm not sure I follow. The MWE produces the output shown. In LyX, just before failing, in TexShop, just before succeeding. The `\sffamily' line is present in both. If I remove it from TeXShop, it fails like LyX does.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2736/discussion-between-egreg-and-raxacoricofallapatorius)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expert` option requires to buy commercial fonts, as is detailed on page 3 of the documentation of `mathdesign`.

The discrepancy in behavior between LyX and TeXShop can be explained by the fact that the example you submitted *doesn't* use Charter small caps because of the `\sffamily` command in the `\fancyhead` line that is probably not present in the file you're using with LyX.

The error message indeed points to

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file bchrc8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
```

and `bchrc8a.pfb` should exactly be Bitstream Charter Expert. Notice that the log excerpt from the TeXShop run mentions `uhvr8a.pfb` (Helvetica), that is in fact used for the header.

Comment: So if I had `\newthought{Now} I see!` TeXShop would fail too (because it would look for charter small caps.

Comment: One final question: The mathdesign manual says I need a "Windows Postscript" version (I assume Mac will do as well). The only way I see of getting that is in a $200 package. Are there generally other sources (for TeX applications like this where the "missing" bits of a package can be acquired go fill gaps in a TeX workflow)?

Comment: The "Windows Postscript" refers simply to the `.pfb` file. Mac OS used to have a different format for font files, but this has not been the case since Mac OS X came out. Only fonts are "the missing bit".

Comment: FWIW, this was not the case for me. I purchase a "Mac PostScript" font and it failed to work. I then purchased the "Windows PostScript" version and it worked fine.