# Are there resources for acquiring elements of commercial fonts specific to TeX?

Tags: fonts

Some TeX packages benefit from the acquisition of specific fonts for best results. For example, `mathdesign` lacks small caps for Bitstream Charter, but supports an "expert" option that makes use of Windows Postscript version of these, that [requires ownership of the relevant font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47479/7844). These formats are, however, generally available as parts of expensive comprehensive bundles.

Are there resources for TeX users that provide a way to purchase the specific font features "missing" from popular TeX packages, without having to purchase expensive bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing specific to TeX, but many of the foundries provide tools for identifying fonts in specific formats and with specific features.

*[FontShop](http://www.fontshop.com/)*, for example, clearly indicates what formats are available for each typeface, and provides tools for testing specific features in any displayed list of fonts . For example, attempting to display small caps in the following example, reveals that the selected typefaces do not support them, while the small format icons indicate the formats available:

[image: FontShop example]

*[MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/)* also indicates all the features supported by a typeface (using the icons at the bottom in the example below) and the format of the font (the icon next to the font name):

[image]

Both sites provide numerous resources for examining the character set and experimenting with different sample text. And there are many other similar sites with similar features.

Comment: Remember that if the goal is to use a font with `mathdesign`, you must acquire the _Windows_ PostScript version (even if you are using a Mac).